# Python 2.7 won't load any modules I installed. Will only load native modules that come with Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

*Note: Please don't comment here that Python 2.7 is depreciated.  I already know this.  I need to get this working first before migrating to 3.x.*

On Windows 10, I had installed (and running correctly) both Python 2.7 and Python 3.7.  Since I only needed Python 2.7, I uninstalled Python 3.7 (and manually deleted respective packages installed under .\Python37*) as well as the virtual environment directory below.  I have no idea if that virtual environment was associated with Python 2.7 or Python 3.7:

```
C:\Users\MKANET\Envs\MKA.NETT
```

After I rebooted, to my horror, every time I run a Python 2.7 script, I get a whole bunch of ambiguous traceback errors when trying to import modules I had installed with PIP (for Python 2.7).  However, **I don't have issues importing the modules like sys, json (packages that come preinstalled with Python 2.7)**.
When executing script below from Windows command-line:

```
& C:/Users/MKANET/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/python27/python.exe c:/Users/MKANET/OneDrive/Dev/Projects/Python/test2.py
```

...I get a bunch of ambiguous traceback errors:.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/MKANET/OneDrive/Dev/Projects/Python/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
  from pypsexec.client import Client
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\pypsexec\client.py", line 8, in <module>
  from smbprotocol.connection import Connection, NtStatus
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\smbprotocol\connection.py", line 33, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import (
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\ciphers\aead.py", line 10, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import aead
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 16, in <module>
  from cryptography import utils, x509
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  from cryptography.x509.base import (
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\base.py", line 18, in <module>
  from cryptography.x509.extensions import Extension, ExtensionType
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 26, in <module>
  from cryptography.x509.general_name import GeneralName, IPAddress, OtherName
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\general_name.py", line 10, in <module>
  from email.utils import parseaddr
File "c:\Users\MKANET\OneDrive\Dev\Projects\Python\email.py", line 11, in <module>
  obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
  dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
  return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
File "C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _GetGoodDispatch
  IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

**UPDATE HUGE CLUE:**
This is ONLY happens when executing scripts in the below folder:

```
C:\Users\Michael\OneDrive\Dev\Projects\Python
```

If I execute a script in any other folder on my C: Drive, modules load perfectly without errors.  I don't know what's different about this folder that causes my modules not load.  Maybe, there's a file in this folder that causing this?

Comment: Unrelated tip: Use another python version (like 3.8) as 2.7 is no longer supported

Comment: Yes, I know.  This is for an existing project that hasn't been migrated over to 3.8.  I have to get this working ASAP.

Comment: what hapenns if you run:
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)

Comment: As mentioned in the post, those modules import just fine.

Comment: What is `sys.prefix` set to?

Comment: Python is expected to look for packages installed in `f"{sys.prefix}\lib\site-packages"`

Comment: C:\Users\MKANET\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python27

Comment: Maybe too obvious too ask... but does this directory actually contain the packages you are trying to import?

Comment: If they don't, try to install something with pip via python: `python -m pip install ...` and try to import that. This way you make sure you're actually using the correct pip (and not the pip for python 3, for example)

Comment: That folder hasn't changed,  All files are in tact as far as I can tell.

Comment: If I install any of the modules I had previously installed for Python 27, I get "Requirement already satisfied: " for all the modules and respective dependencies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211749/discussion-between-mkanet-and-tomasito665).

Comment: Are you using virtual environments or anything similar?

Comment: This whole issue started when I mistakenly deleted a virtual environment (as mentioned in my post) and uninstalled Python 3.7.  I thought that virtual environment was related to Python 3.7, however, I'm not sure.  How can I confirm if Python 2.7 interpreter is looking in the virtual environment or not?  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: I just manually copied site-packages dir contents to a virtual environment.  I am seeing the SAME errors when importing these modules.  Something in the system is interfering with Python 2.7 in importing these modules.

Answer (score 0):

Since this issue was limited only to scripts inside the below directory:

```
C:\Users\Michael\OneDrive\Dev\Projects\Python
```

I was able to narrow the issue down to a file called, `email.py`. If I tried to import a module for example, requests; for some odd reason an `email.pyc` would get created; followed by the import module errors.  All I did was rename email.py to mail.py.. and, this whole issue finally stopped.

I have no idea why Python 2.7 is sensitive to that file name, but changing it to something else resolved the issue for me.  Maybe, someone could comment on why the file name breaks things; especially when I had a `__init__.py` in the same directory to import another module.